# Add collapsible container to newForm

Tags: 2010, list

I'd like to create a custom NewForm/EditForm for adding list items.

There are currently ~50 fields that can be filled out, and I would like to add some sort of collapsible container - or maybe an accordian container - to hold groups of ~10 fields each.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Maybe there is a jquery library?

Comment: you can try to ask @omlin this question. In [this post](http://omlin.blogspot.com/2011/06/list-form-sharepoint.html) he described how to add tabs to the new list form and move fields to these tads. One problem... this post in russian ((( but you can try to look at the [source code](https://sites.google.com/site/omlinfiles/TabbedListForms.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marc Anderson had a [great blog](http://sympmarc.com/2011/08/18/taming-long-sharepoint-list-forms-using-jquery-to-break-them-into-sections/) post on the subject using jQuery and jQueryUI.  I haven't used it yet, but is very promising.  It is based on 2007, but the code should be easily adapted to the 2010 output.

You can test it [here](http://www.sympraxisconsulting.com/demos/Demo%20Pages/ComplicatedList.aspx).